# Error generating variable with 44 characters in Jmeter

Tags: java, variables, automation, jmeter, barcode

hello!

I have the following problem in Jmeter:

I want to add a code to my BeanShell Tester that generates a 44-character barcode. But so far, without success.

So I went to plan "B":
I added a Random Variable with 44 characters, but it doesn't get created. It does not display any errors.

Could someone help me and tell me what I can do to make it work?

> Below are the variables:

```
Output format: 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Minimum value: 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Maximum value: 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999
```

Print below:
[image]

As for the code, I didn't share it here, but if anyone knows and has a code that generates barcodes, I'd appreciate it!

Anyway, that's it folks!

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing Beanshell scripting (however [since JMeter 3.1 you should be using Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/is-beanshell-dead)) the better option would be doing something like:

```
vars.put("CodeBarra", org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils.randomNumeric(44));
```

Alternatively you can use it in [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy):

```
${__groovy(org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils.randomNumeric(44),CodeBarra)}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use JMeter function [__RandomString](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString) (last parameter is the variable name)

```
${__RandomString(44,0123456789,CodeBarra)}
```

> returns a random String of length using characters in chars to use

Comment: Very thanks!!! I achieved!